# Create Menu options button in Tablet

Tags: android, menu, tablet

How to create a soft button for tablets? Now I have the manifest minSDK 8, and the target of targetSDK = 13. On phones everything is normal, there is no button on the plates

Comment: Do you want to display navigation with soft buttons or hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, there are 3 parameters that you can use with soft buttons naviagtion:

The **SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE** flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN flag. 
When set, this flag enables “low profile" mode for the system bar or navigation bar.

The **SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE** flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE flag to request the system bar or navigation bar be visible.

The **SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION** is a new flag that requests the navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the navigation bar used by some handsets (it does not hide the system bar on tablets).

Try to use:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: The problem was solved by setting the manifest of the targetSDK="10"